# Can i use excel function in pivot table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In excel pivot table (data are derived from database), how can I do a calculation on selected field ? example below, value of column G is equal to 'sum all value from column A to E then total sum minus with value F'. How can I do this calculation in pivot table without touching database ?

```
A    B    C    D    E    F    G
100  200  300  400  500  989
```

Comment: It depends on your pivot table. If columns A-F are from different fields in the Values field, you can do that, but if, say, A-C are from  one field split through column labels and so do D-F, then no.

Comment: A fairly standard formula in Col G, outside the pivot table, may achieve all that you need. i.e. `G2=sum(a2:e2)-f2` then copy down as far as you need. Or even `G2=if(a2<>"",sum(a2:e2)-f2,"")` and copy that *all* the way down the column. That variation allows the pivot table to shrink or grow on refresh without leaving spurious zeros in col G.

Comment: You can also add a computed column in the pivot table

Answer (score 0):

Jerry is right you can add "calculated field" in your pivot using following formula only if all A-f are different fields/columns in database.

to add calculated filed follow following steps:

1. click anywhere in your pivot

2.then select on calculated field button in Options ribbon under formulas. or press Alt+JTJF on keyboard.

1. type new column name in "name" and enter following formula in "formula" and click ok

Formula:

```
= A+ B+ C+ D+ E- F
```

You can replace A,B,C,D,E,F with actual names/titles of columns.